# Can not use the utility whose path have been added to system environment variables in Conemu environment

Tags: path, windows-10

i have just begin to use Conemu, but i do not know why i cannot use basic utility suddenly. such as **ping**.

it prompted:

```
C:\Users\seeed>ping baidu.com
'ping' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

And with Command prompt(the same result with the situation in Conemu), i have to set current directory to **c:\windows\system32** so i can use some utility such as ping.

```
c:\Windows\System32>ping baidu.com

Pinging baidu.com [123.125.114.144] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 123.125.114.144: bytes=32 time=59ms TTL=52
Reply from 123.125.114.144: bytes=32 time=54ms TTL=52
Reply from 123.125.114.144: bytes=32 time=58ms TTL=52
Reply from 123.125.114.144: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=52

Ping statistics for 123.125.114.144:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 54ms, Maximum = 59ms, Average = 57ms
```

FYI,I use Windows 10 pro and i have utility path to system environment variable.

Comment: You question does not relate to ConEmu. You have to learn about "PATH" variable.

Comment: ok, Windows recovered itself  this morning. but i can not assure it will recovery itself for every computer.